# Set-AzureSubscription : Cannot bind parameter 'Certificate'

Tags: powershell, azure-storage

While changing `CurrentStorageAccountName` in azure account using PowerShell I am getting following error:

```
Set-AzureSubscription : Cannot bind parameter 'Certificate'. Cannot convert value
"0EA9BE03CD1C2E5B93DB176F89C2CC2EF147B96C" to type "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2".
Error: "The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Code is :

```
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName Enterprise -Certificate 0EA9BE03CD1C2E5B93DB176F89C2CC2EF147B96C -CurrentStorageAccountName btestps -SubscriptionId XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: `get-help set-azuresubscription -full`

Comment: The help contains a couple of examples of using a certificate thumbprint and how to apply that to `-Certificate`

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to do this, you need to actually get or build an X509Certificate2 object that you then pass through to the -certificate parameter.

To set the certificate with a certificate from the local user certificate store by thumbprint you can:

```
# open the local user certificate store as read-only 
$store = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]::CurrentUser)
$store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadOnly)
# get all the certificates in the store
$certs = $store.Certificates;
# restrict the selection to only currently valid certificates
$currentcerts = $certs.Find([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType]::FindByTimeValid, [System.DateTime]::Now, 0)
# get the first certificate by thumbprint, you could also find by distinguished name, subject name, etc 
$signingCert = $currentcerts.Find([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType]::FindByThumbprint,"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",0)[0]
# set the certificate
set-azuresubscription -certificate $signingCert
# open the local user certificate store as read-only 
$store = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]::CurrentUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

A some what simpler solution is to use this:

```
$Certificate = Get-Item cert:\\LocalMachine\My\$CertificateThumbprint
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName Enterprise -Certificate $Certificate
```

Assuming that the certificate is in LocalMachine\My.